# Gas cost difference between uint[] and mapping(uint => uint)

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, data-types

When mapping for example a large integer to some integer,

```
uint[] index;
index.length = 1000000;
index[600001] = 4;
```

is it cheaper to use

```
mapping(uint => uint) index;
index[600001] = 4;
```

? one benefit of using `uint[]` is that it can be deleted, happens to be useful in a dApp I work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would be the same, with one modification.

You would go

```
uint[1000000] index;
// index.length = 1000000; not needed
```

The dynamic index you used is only *slightly* more expensive than the fixed-length array suggested because it needs another 32-byte word for the array length and the extra step of setting it.

Both methods use a 32-byte key to point to a 32-byte word. Both methods will avoid writing unnecessarily and values default to 0 in indexes that haven't been written to.

Neither method benefits from reducing the precision of the values pointed to (to, say, `uint8`) because a 32-byte word is the smallest space they can address.

Hope it helps.

Comment: will be continuously adjusting the length, so have to use dynamic arrays I think

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Be careful if your adjustments involve reorganizing the list. There are some non-obvious challenges to content with.